# How to derive the equation $\sum s_n z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}\sum a_n z^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I posted [If the radius of convergence of the series $\sum a_n z^n$ is $R$, what's the radius of convergence of $\sum s_n z^n$, where $s_n$ partial sum of $a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4247878/if-the-radius-of-convergence-of-the-series-sum-a-n-zn-is-r-whats-the-rad?noredirect=1#comment8830417_4247878).  But no answer. One of hint is given. But  i struggled to prove that, then only I can understand how to prove that. Maybe we can use geometrical series, or is it written as Cauchy product?

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s_nz^n=s_0+s_1z+s_2z^2+...$$
$$=a_0+(a_0+a_1)z+(a_0+a_1+a_2)z^2+...$$
$$=a_0(1+z+z^2+...)+a_1z(1+z+z^2+...)+a_2z^2(1+z+z^2+...)+...$$
$$=(1+z+z^2+...)(a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...)=...$$

Comment: So the radius of convergence is minimum of $1$ and the radius of convergence?

Comment: The radius of convergence of the Cauchy product is at least the minimum of $1$ and $R$. See [Mertens theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Convergence_and_Mertens.27_theorem).

Comment: Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: multiply the left hand side by $1-z$, you'll get a telescoping sum. (If you're unfamiliar with this, try to read a proof of the geometrical sum/series formula)